# Wilcoxon Signed Rank Critical Values for n >40

Tags: statistical-significance, references, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm looking for critical values for Wilcoxon Signed Rank for larger values of N but can only find tables and lists for up to N=40. I am looking for either comprehensive sources of critical values for a much larger range of N, or a way to calculate these critical values myself for any given value of N and different levels of significance.

Comment: Have you tried `dwilcox` [in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Wilcoxon.html) ?

Comment: I don't use R myself but my partner does. I'll have a look.

Comment: Above that point you should usually be able to use the normal approximation

Comment: @Glen_b I did find a formula for the normal approximation, but I don't know how to use or adjust it for different levels of significance, i.e. .05, .01,.001.

Comment: Perhaps that's the question you ought to be asking.  It certainly has a simpler answer than the one you asked.  The [Wikipedia article on this test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) contains a brief explanation of how to use the Normal approximation (aka "z score").  Any elementary statistics textbook published in the last 150 years or so will provide detailed instructions--that gives you a great many accessible resources to refer to!

Comment: @Whuber Ah, I didn't realise normal approximation _is_ the z-score. That helps!

Comment: @whuber If you add your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not an acceptable answer for this site: it neither answers the question you posted nor does it have enough detail to be directly useful.

Comment: @Serafina are you using tables or finding your normal critical values in some other fashion?

Comment: @Glen_b I would usually look up critical values in any of a number of textbooks but this time I'd rather be able to calculate them myself, if possible.

Comment: You want to *calculate* normal critical values? With pen and paper? or in some other fashion?

Comment: @Glen_b By hand or in Excel.

Comment: In Excel you use normsinv to get critical values and/or normsdist to get p-values from test statistics

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you. I've now figured out how to solve my initial problem. I found the appropriate functions to calculate the z-score and to calculate the critical values in Excel to the point that it matches the results I get in SPSS. 

What's the etiquette in these cases? Is there a way to close my question or should I write up the way I am calculating it in Excel, with the caveat that I know _that_ it works, but not quite _why_ ...